# How to remove the <p> and <br> from my profile description

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw it in many user's profile, I don't mind having it but it is a little bit annoying.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185610/how-to-remove-the-%3Cp%3E-and-%3Cbr%3E-from-my-profile-description/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like a bug. You should file a ticket in the [answers.ros.org issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-09**:
Issue is file here for reference: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/86 .